# Why my button is inline with a flex box in a column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

My button is **in line** with the flex-box,
Elements should be stacked on top of one another in a **column**, right?

I am making a timer, so there is a row, in which there are two columns.

In one column there is an **image** and in the other, there is a **heading**, a **flexbox**(which contains four rectangles), and a **button**.

Now, I want my button to be below my timer, but it is in line with it.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stiks</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>


                <div class="container hero">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="portal col-md-12 col-lg-5">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/download (10).jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-7 align-self-center">

      <h2><b>Timer</b></h2>

      <div class="d-inline-flex flex-nowrap">
        <div class="rect">
          <span class="days"></span>
          <p>Days</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rect">
          <span class="hours"></span>
          <p>Hours</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rect">
          <span class="minutes"></span>
          <p>Minutes</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rect">
          <span class="seconds"></span>
          <p>Seconds</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn-main" type="button">Start</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
:root{
    --yellow: #fff189;
    --grey: #444444;
    --off-white: #e6e6e6;
    --blue: #047db1;
    --pink: #6b093d;
    --green: #ccf0a9;
    --black: #000000;
}


h1{
    font-size: 4.2em;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.section{
    padding-right: 5vw;
    padding-left: 5vw;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}




/*------------------------------------hero section------------------------------------*/
.hero{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.timer{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}


.rect{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--off-white);
    background-color: var(--blue);
    height: 6.5em;
    width: 8em;
    min-width: 0;
}

.rect h1{
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
}


.btn-main{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 00.5em;
    background-color: var(--pink);
    color: var(--off-white);
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.6em;
    padding-right: 1.8em;
    padding-left: 1.8em;
}

.btn-main:hover{
   background-color: var(--grey);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: block;` css in .btn-main class.
visit : https://jsfiddle.net/ktv1frwu/

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code according to browser's width it changes to inline and sometime below those boxes.

**Fix it by adding**

***display : block in your .btn-main class***

```css
.btn-main{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: if you css file in css folder than try second one !

Comment: It is correct brother because I have defined the background color in the CSS file. And I can see the background color applied to the website. If the structure was not correct, the color would not have been applied to the background.

Comment: Oh! finally got what is the actual confusion behind this. As you resize the window sometime button goto inline and sometime below those boxes.